# Unable to transfer text file data to arduino using python program

Tags: python, arduino

I am new to both arduino and python and have been unable to locate a working answer. Currently, my project requires that I send data to my arduino uno from a text file. I have been trying to use a python program to read values from the text file and send them to my arduino. The arduino should then use these values to operate a motor. I have tried more simple tests, like sending a high and low signal to the motor, but the issue seems to arise when sending integers and floats as input for analogWrite(). I would prefer to use floats for more precision but a working system is more important.

Edit: Fixed by changing b'number' to number.encode(). I am still curious about a workaround for the Serial.available() issue.

**Arduino**:

```
const int motorPin = 9;
float input = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  if (Serial.available()) {
    Serial.println("data has been entered");
    float x = Serial.parseFloat();
    if (x > 0) {
      input = x;
      analogWrite(motorPin, input);
    }
  }
  Serial.print(input);
  Serial.println(" was used");
}
```

As a side note, I was also having an issue where Serial.available() would always return true after reading all values and I would read in one extra value of 0. That's the reasoning for the second if statement. If there's a better work around, please let me know. I would like to read in 0's if they are in the data.

**Python**:

```
import serial
import time

#Set by deault to COM4 -- change as needed
arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)

#Allow connection between the ports to clear 
time.sleep(2)

#Start an infinite loop to send data from acceleration text file to Arduino
f = open("accel_vals-1.txt", "r")
while 1:
    #will need to check later on if file can write while loop is running
    for number in f:
        arduino.write(b'number')
        print(number + " entered")
        time.sleep(1)

#Close file after program ends
f.close()
```

**Text File**:

```
0
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
80
90
100
90
80
70
60
50
40
30
20
10
0
100
200
250
200
100
0
```

Comment: `arduino.write(b'number')` will send the string `"number"`. I think you meant: `arduino.write(number.encode())`

Comment: Thank you! That was the bug.